# XSLT - remove multiple nodes and add new node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This may be a simple xslt problem. I have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <chap>
        <p>This is a para</p>
    </chap>
</doc>
```

what I need is remove both `<doc>` and `<chap>` node and add  node to the result three.

SO the output should be,

```
<new>
   <p>This is a para</p>
</new>
```

when I write a template to

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
      <new><xsl:apply templates/></new>
   </template>
```

it adds `<chap>` to result tree.

when I write a template to `<chap>`

```
 <xsl:template match="chap">
      <new><xsl:apply templates/></new>
   </template>
```

it adds `<doc>` to result tree.

and I cannot suppress any element like `<xsl:template match="chap"/>`. as it removes child nodes as well.

How Can I get desired output using xsl?

Comment: Apparently, you have other templates in your stylesheet that you don't show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<xsl:template match="doc"><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:template>`, then you can use your

```
<xsl:template match="chap">
      <new><xsl:apply templates/></new>
</template>
```

together with the identity transformation template you probably have too (although you haven't shown it).